# get only key from map

Tags: java, dictionary

I have a `Map<String, List<List<Double>>>` with only one key, e.g.

```
{onlyKey=[[1.0, 2.3, 20.1], [6.5, -9.3, 4.5]]}
```

But I don't actually know what the name of the key is.

How can I get the name of the only key stored within the map?

[Answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49737840/3310334).

I know that `keySet` exists, but I already tried `map.keySet().get(0)` and `Set` doesn't have a `get(int)` method. Pretty sure sets are generally used when you know (or have some idea of) what they contain.

Comment: `map.keySet()`?

Comment: @csmckelvey how do I get the only element of that, already tried `.get(0)`

Comment: You have to iterate the keySet - in your case it will only have 1 iteration but you still need to iterate to get it. `for (String key : map.keySet())` is one way.

Comment: Start reading the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Set.html). The `Set` class does not offer a `get` method as seen there. Use the `iterator` method to retrieve an iterator: `map.keySet().iterator().next()`. Here is the [official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html) for Set.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used `map.keySet().iterator().next()` to get the only key within the map.

Comment: Yes, as we stated

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos as no answer states?

Comment: We told you where to get and i told to iterate, the other dude added as a comment

Comment: I think if Zabuza had posted this answer it would have been upvoted.

Answer (score 5):

The `Map<First, Second>` has the method `keySet()` that returns a `Set<First>` of the key.

Also: There's `entrySet()` that returns a `Set<Entry<First, Second>>`.

Note that return is a `Set` and not a `List`, the order of insertion is not preserved nor you have access to `get(int index)`, you need to iterate over a set to get a first value.

Answer (score 3):

From the [Map Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) you can see you can use `keySet()` to recover the `Set` of all keys in your `Map`, which, in your case, will contain your only key.

Comment: How do I get the only element of the keyset

Comment: @minseong `map.keySet().iterator().next()` returns the first (and only) key. It's just a regular `Set`. Check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) and the official tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative for using `iterator` you might use `stream()` and `findFirst()`:

```
map.keySet().stream().findFirst().get()
```